# What is the equal sign with 3 lines mean in Wilson's theorem?

Tags: notation, self-learning

I'm reading up on [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), and see a symbol I don't know... what does an equal sign with three lines mean?

I'm looking at the example table and I still can't infer what they are trying to say about that relationship between equations.

Comment: This concept is called [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: $a \equiv b \bmod m$, read $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $m$, represents equality between the remainders of $a$ and $b$ when divided by $m$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(n-1)! \equiv -1\pmod n$$ means that $(n-1)!$ and $-1$ differ by a multiple of $n$.  Or, if you prefer, that $(n-1)!+1$ is a multiple of $n$.

In general, $$a\equiv b\pmod n$$ means that $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $n$, or that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$.

It's explained in detail in [the Wikipedia article on "modular equivalence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). The $\equiv$ symbol itself is pronounced "is equivalent to".

Comment: This is Perfect! Thanks... now I have a better route to take to study.  Since I never learned this in school, what class should have exposed this to me?  (given I went to school in the early 90's and am certain I was never taught it)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "school", and where or when you might have learned it depends on the curriculum. An undergraduate-level class in elementary number theory would have covered it.

Answer (score 2):

Wilson's Theorem:

$$(n-1)!\ \equiv\ -1 \pmod n.$$

It means "is congruent to" (modulo n): that is, $$(n - 1)! -(-1) = (n - 1)! + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod n$$ And that simply means that $n$ divides $(n - 1)! + 1$.

Comment: Needs a TU ----> =+1

Comment: $\Longrightarrow + \Longleftarrow$

Answer (score 1):

a ≡ b (mod n)

is equivalent to

a mod n = b   :(if b less than n)

a mod n = b mod n :(else)

(I am not sure, if also b>0).